# Iterating through an excel drop down menu and extracting data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataset that has healthcare information on every county in America. I am just trying to extract one value from each county, Actual Health Costs per Capita (AB27).

The problem I am having is that the dataset uses a drop down list to pull up each county's information. When I try and create a pandas dataframe, it only gets the drop down list.

Ideally, I'd be able to iterate over the dataset and extract each county's name and Actual Health Costs per Capita (AB27) into a pandas dataframe.

Any ideas?

[image: A picture of the dataset and drop down list]

Comment: I am guessing there is some VBA code or something similar that pulls the data from a database and displays it in excel. Any chance you looked at the macros of the excel?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky I am most definitely over my head here, I am totally ignorant on the subject of VBA and excel macros. I do think you are right though, when I check the content of cell AB27 it reads: =VLOOKUP($P$7,'State_county 2019'!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Report!A28,'State_county 2019'!$2:$2,0),0)

Comment: thanks for the code. The vlookup and match functions are typically used to perform joins or data mergers in excel so it is nowhere as complicated as I thought. Presumably, all of the data are already in the excel file. As an alternative to the below answer, it may sensible to just read the whole report sheet in and then find the "actual health costs per capita" among the data rows using pandas or other python tools.

Comment: ah ok that is simpler. I'll look around for some guides on how to expand the report sheet but if you have any advice that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just pandas will be cumbersome.

Use [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/).

The dropdown list in B3 is probably sourced from a range within the Excel file. In the case that changing the value of B3 also changes the value of AB27 to the one of the respective county, I would suggest the following:

1. identify the range which is feeding B3 cell and get the data from that range into one pandas dataframe or a simple list - this will be your main iteration source
2. create a new list, where you will store the Actual Health Costs per Capita data
3. iterate through the previously mentioned list of counties
4. in each iteration set the value of B3 to your current iteration element
5. append the value of AB27 into the results list, together with the county name, e.g. as dicts

Code example:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

workbook = xw.Book('D:/Book1.xlsx')
report = workbook.sheets['Sheet1']
county_sheet = workbook.sheets['Sheet2']
counties = county_sheet.range('A1:A3')
results = []
for county in counties:
    report.range('A1').value = county.value
    results.append(
        {
            'County': county.value,
            'Actual Health Costs per Capita': report.range('A2').value
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: thanks for the help! That makes sense to me, though I am running into an error when I try this approach. It is giving me an attribute error for the  report['B3'].value = county.value and saying that 'str' item has no attribute 'value'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Edited, try dropping .value from report['B3'] and report['AB27']

Comment: That worked for the report, but now its complaining about the county.value, saying a tuple does not have the attribute value.

Comment: You are right. There was also a couple of other issues - it's not possible with openpyxl afterall. Therefore please see my edit using xlwings library. I tested that and worked fine for me in my dummy excel file. As xlwings are using MS Excel engine, you must have MS Excel installed on the machine where you run the script. A2 from my script is AB27 and A1 is B3 in your excel file. If it works for you, please accept the answer, thank you.